# XML - can't select nodes in a different part of xml once used parameters higher up, Windows Phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to be able to output the two routes in this service, only if it matches the a node before the routes do.

XML:

```
   <Service z:Id="i5">
      <EntityKey z:Id="i6" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
        <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
        <a:EntityKeyValues>
          <a:EntityKeyMember>
            <a:Key>serviceId</a:Key>
            <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1150</a:Value>
          </a:EntityKeyMember>
        </a:EntityKeyValues>
        <a:EntitySetName>ServiceSet</a:EntitySetName>
      </EntityKey>
      <client z:Ref="i3" />
      <clientReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i4" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </clientReference>
      <journeyPreferredService />
      <newsArticles />
      <place />
      <primaryUrl>http://www.buses.co.uk/1A</primaryUrl>
      <relativePosition>2</relativePosition>
      <routes>
        <Route z:Id="i7">
          <EntityKey z:Id="i8" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
            <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
            <a:EntityKeyValues>
              <a:EntityKeyMember>
                <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1232</a:Value>
              </a:EntityKeyMember>
            </a:EntityKeyValues>
            <a:EntitySetName>RouteSet</a:EntitySetName>
          </EntityKey>
          <POI />
          <POILines />
          <dateEffectiveFrom>2012-09-01T00:00:00</dateEffectiveFrom>
          <dateEffectiveTo i:nil="true" />
          <isLive>true</isLive>
          <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
          <routeDescription i:nil="true" />
          <routeId>1232</routeId>
          <routeMap />
          <routeName>1A Whitehawk - Mile Oak</routeName>
          <route_stop />
          <route_stop_stop />
          <route_stop_timetable_stop />
          <service z:Ref="i5" />
          <serviceReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
            <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i6" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
          </serviceReference>
          <timetables />
          <validDestination>Mile Oak</validDestination>
        </Route>
        <Route z:Id="i9">
          <EntityKey z:Id="i10" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
            <a:EntityContainerName>busExpressEntities</a:EntityContainerName>
            <a:EntityKeyValues>
              <a:EntityKeyMember>
                <a:Key>routeId</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1236</a:Value>
              </a:EntityKeyMember>
            </a:EntityKeyValues>
            <a:EntitySetName>RouteSet</a:EntitySetName>
          </EntityKey>
          <POI />
          <POILines />
          <dateEffectiveFrom>2012-09-01T00:00:00</dateEffectiveFrom>
          <dateEffectiveTo i:nil="true" />
          <isLive>true</isLive>
          <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
          <routeDescription i:nil="true" />
          <routeId>1236</routeId>
          <routeMap />
          <routeName>1A Mile Oak - Whitehawk</routeName>
          <route_stop />
          <route_stop_stop />
          <route_stop_timetable_stop />
          <service z:Ref="i5" />
          <serviceReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
            <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i6" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
          </serviceReference>
          <timetables />
          <validDestination>Whitehawk</validDestination>
        </Route>
      </routes>
      <serviceAbbreviatedName />
      <serviceDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</serviceDescription>
      <serviceIconUrl></serviceIconUrl>
      <serviceId>1150</serviceId>
      <serviceName>1A</serviceName>
      <serviceNotes />
      <serviceText>Whitehawk - Mile Oak</serviceText>
      <serviceUrls />
    </Service>
```

I have been trying to get the following code to work, but the select line does not seem to be working as it's throwing an error.

```
var list2 = (from item in loadedData.Descendants(ns + "ArrayOfService").Descendants(ns + "Service").Descendants(ns + "client").Descendants(ns + "services").Descendants(ns + "Service")
                           where (string)item.Element(ns + "serviceDescription") == textSearchBox.Text
                           select (string)item.Descendants(ns + "routes").Descendants(ns + "Route").Element(ns + "routeName")).FirstOrDefault();                          
              test1.Text = list2;
```

Any ideas on what I need to add/change to make sue that I only select the routes within this service?

Comment: what was the error message?

Comment: Error 144 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: okay, check my answer for quick fix to that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.Descendants()` you should've tried using `.Element()` in the `select` clause :

```
.......
select (string)item.Element(ns + "routes")
                   .Element(ns + "Route")
                   .Element(ns + "routeName")
.......
```

`Element()` is better than `Descendants()` performance wise, and most importantly fix the compile time error you got.

`Element()` used to select the first occurrence of specific element that is direct child of current element. For example, `<routes>` is direct child of `<Service>` so we can do `item.Element("routes")`.

Your LINQ `from` clause seems can be optimized in the similar way.

Comment: That's great - Now working. Also how can I select both routes in one select command or two?

Comment: Try to modify `from` clause to end with all `<Route>`s like : `...Element(ns + "routes").Element**s**(ns + "Route")`. Then this `select` clause will return `<routeName>` from both routes : `select (string)item.Element(ns + "routeName")`